# Left-border on a button doesn't work in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a pipe between two buttons using `border-left` property. Instead of using a separate `div`.

My `HTML` is as follows:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <button class="search-field__submit-button" type="submit">
        <img src="search.svg">
    </button>
</transition>

<div v-show="searchInput" class="search-field__wrapper">
    <button class="search-field__reset-button" type="reset" @click="reset">
        <img src="close.svg">
    </button>
</div>
```

My `CSS` is as follows:

```
.search-field__submit-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search-field__submit-button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid var(--color-blue-active);
}

.search-field__submit-button img {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
}

.search-field__wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 4rem;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search-field__spinner,
.search-field__reset-button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-field__reset-button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid var(--color-blue-active);
}

.search-field__reset-button img {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
}

.search-field__reset-button::after {
    border-right: 2rem solid red;
}                                        //this is what I am trying
```

**Tried:** Using `border-left` for submit_button and also `border-right`for the reset_button. But none of them has worked. I used `::before` pesudo element.

**Problem:** The right border on the reset_button is not visible at all. Where are things wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a bit confusing as you're using border-right, but say border-left. You'll get more help if your question is consistent and clear. Try removing `.search-field__reset-button::after` and adding `margin-left: 5px; border-left: 2rem solid red;` to `.search-field__reset-button`

Comment: are you trying to do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f4s2mtp7/)??

Comment: @Red you can see I tried both properties for different buttons to at least display the vertical pipe between two buttons. So doesn't matter `border-left` or `border-right` property does the work.

Comment: @shaz - you are trying it on a `::after`, not the button itself. I'm asking you to try it on the button, and adding a margin to make sure there's a space to see it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::after` pseudoelement should have `content` property to be shown. If you have no need in content, just set it to empty value like that:

```
.search-field__reset-button::after {
    content: '';
    border-right: 2rem solid red;
}
```